# How to open CustomDialog when click item in listView

Tags: android

Hi i'm new on this site and i have a problem with my app. I have this function and i want that when item_info is pressed i open a custom dialog linked below but it keeps me saying that custom dialog requires an activity and in the onClick i'm in the customAdapter class. Please help me

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    int position=(Integer) v.getTag();
    Object object= getItem(position);
    DataModel dataModel=(DataModel)object;

    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.item_info:
CustomDialogActivity cda = new CustomDialogActivity(this, "SHOW");

            break;
    }
}
```

This is my customDialog extract with the constructor

```
class CustomDialogActivity extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

public Activity c;
public Dialog d;
public Button yes, no;
String addOrShow;

public CustomDialogActivity(Activity a, String dialogType) {

    super(a);
    this.c = a;
    this.addOrShow = dialogType;
}

}
```

Thanks in advance!